# Help listing elements of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[![Question in question][1]][1]

Basically I think I've worked it out to {(0,0),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,2) ect} but I know I'm not meant to just list them out can advise me how I should be writing it or whether I've gone wrong. Thank you.

Comment: How did you work this out?

Comment: First determine $({\Bbb Q}\times {\Bbb Z})\cap ({\Bbb Z}\times{\Bbb Q})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have $$\left( \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z} \right) \cap \left( \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q} \right) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$$

Indeed, $(a,b) \in \left( \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Z} \right) \cap \left( \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q} \right) \Leftrightarrow a \in \mathbb{Z} \cap \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } b \in \mathbb{Z} \cap \mathbb{Q} \Leftrightarrow a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then the elements you are looking for are the $(a,b)$ such that $a,b$ are relative integers, and one of them is negative.